# C Array of Linked List Struct on Heap

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory

```
typedef struct cache_line {
    char valid;
    mem_addr_t tag;
    struct cache_line* next;
} cache_line_t;

typedef cache_line_t* cache_set_t;
typedef cache_set_t* cache_t;


/* The cache we are simulating */
cache_t cache;


void initCache()
{
        cache = malloc (S * sizeof(cache_set_t));
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i ++ ){
                cache[i]= malloc(sizeof(cache_line_t));
                cache_line_t *temp = *(cache+i);

                temp -> valid = 0;
                temp -> tag = 0;
                cache_line_t* curr = *(cache+ i );
                for (int j = 1; j < E; j++){
                        curr.next = malloc(sizeof(cache_line_t));
                        curr = curr.next;
                        curr.valid=0;
                        curr.tag=0;
                }
                curr.next = NULL;
        }

}
```

So my head is swimming trying to remember all the details of pointers and structs and I've been up for a while trying to finish this project. What I'm trying to do here is allocate an array of this structure (a linked list) on the heap and I keep having issues with type mismatches and whatnot (sorry if its messy I keep on trying new things and recompiling). Any help on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: What's so cool with typedefing pointers...really?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Income security. It makes ones code is so awful that no one can stand to debug it but oneself.

Comment: I have no idea lol, the skeleton code came like that, I thought it was really weird too

Comment: @StoryTeller I doubt about the validity to "oneself" also...:)

Comment: @genericmathstudent - It's not only weird, it's harmful. The person who provided you with this code thought they were doing "abstraction" when in fact they were preforming obfuscation.

Comment: it probably means that when you're doing `sizeof(cache_set_t)`, you're not getting what you expected

Comment: `curr.next  = malloc(...);` :: you are confusing `.` and `->` here ...

Comment: Somebody please just delete this question if the current edit version is all that's left.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the fact the code is terribly obfuscated with abuse of `typedef` probably goes a long way towards both yours and the compilers problems. I wouldn't have a single typedef in this program myself. It serves no real abstraction here. Here's what I'd suggest (with some omission of error checking):

```
struct cache_line {
    char valid;
    mem_addr_t tag;
    struct cache_line* next;
};

struct cache_line** cache;

void initCache()
{
    cache = malloc (sizeof(*cache) * S);
    for (int i = 0; i < S; i ++ ){
        struct cache_line** curr_p = &cache[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < E; j++){
            *curr_p = malloc(sizeof(**curr_p));
            (*curr_p)->valid = 0;
            (*curr_p)->tag = 0;
            (*curr_p)->next = NULL;
            curr_p = &(*curr_p)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Key things to note:

1. I removed all the typedefs. They served no real purpose here but an attempt to save typing. And they did it at the cost of code quality. I also removed it from the `struct`, since I believe the previous statement applies to it as well.
2. I allocated memory canonically. By writing `malloc(sizeof(*pointer_variable))`, you allocate enough memory regardless of what `pointer_variable` points at. It's somewhat type agnostic.
3. I traverse the linked list with the "link traversal" idiom. Instead of keeping track of the "node", I keep track of the pointer that is pointing at the node. In the beginning it's `cache[i]`, and at every iteration it becomes the pointer inside the newly allocated node.